# PyCharm can't resolve references to PyQT5 modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pycharm, virtualenv

I'm trying to learn how to use PyQT5. I created a new folder under my user profile and spun up a virtualenv (and installed PyQT5 from pip3) in a folder called `env`. I created the project in another folder called `guis` and pointed PyCharm to the `env` environment. Pycharm can't find the submodules but sees `PyQT5.QtWidgets` just fine.

Screnshot:
[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I got it to work by removing PyQT5 from

```
Settings > Project > Project Interpreter
```

and reinstalling it **within PyCharm**.

Restart PyCharm afterwards.

Comment: Does this install it with pip or conda?  I prefer to let conda manage stuff where possible.

Comment: It didn't work for me, I got same issue with PySIde2

Comment: Thanks. After installing PyQt5 via PyCharm, it mumbled "updating skeletons for '.virtualenvs/...", and afterwords I had to restart PyCharm. Then it worked. I'll add that in the answer, as it possibly helps, and doesn't do harm ;-)

Comment: The first working solution after several hours of searching. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 9):

I had to go to `File --> Invalidate Caches / Restart` as well

Comment: This actually worked pretty good. Under windows PyCharm now resolves the stubbed \_\_init\_\_.py's in `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\.PyCharmxxxx.x\system\python_stubs\xxxxx\PySide2\..`

Answer (score -1):

In my case i had non-latin symbols in path to python (in AppData). I made new windows user with only-latin name, using it instead of original user fixed the problem.

Answer (score -1):

setting -> project interpreter -> click setting icon -> add -> new environment -> ( add path) -> check 'inherit global site-packages' and 'make available to all projects' -> click OK

always use same environment or you can use different environment for different projects, just check global packages

Comment: The question states he installed pyqt with pip3